# Filter items from an InlinePanel in wagtail

Tags: wagtail

For a small listing of events I used an `InlinePanel` in my page model. Now I would like to filter these events by date, like I would do when using a `@property` with subpages: `date__gte=date.today()` for only displaying the future events on the page `TourdatenIndexPag`. How to achieve that?

My implementation:

```
class EventItem(LinkFields):
    date = models.DateField("Datum")
    ...

    panels = [FieldPanel('date')]

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class TourdatenPageEventItem(Orderable, EventItem):
    page = ParentalKey('md.TourdatenIndexPage', related_name='event_items')


class TourdatenIndexPage(Page):
    ...
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        InlinePanel('event_items', label="Events"),
    ]
```

Where and how could these `event_items` be accessed and filtered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a method on your page model to return the queryset you want:

```
class TourdatenIndexPage(Page):
    def future_event_items(self):
        return self.event_items.filter(date__gte=date.today())
```

Then, on your template, you can refer to `self.future_event_items`:

```
{% for event in self.future_event_items %}
    <li>{{ event.date }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```